# JSP XML Filewriter giving a NullpointerException

Tags: xml, jsp, nullpointerexception, filewriter

The following code is giving me this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>     java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source)
>     java.io.FileWriter.(Unknown Source)

```
SAXBuilder parser = new SAXBuilder();
this.document = parser.build(path);

//changes on the doc happening here

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);
XMLOutputter out = new XMLOutputter();
out.output(this.document, writer);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

How come? It the file locked or something?

On a sidenote: What is the advantage of using BufferedOutputStream classes?

Comment: Chekout the file exist and accessible at given `path` location. Problem lies there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a wrong path to the file, like suggested.